# Install Linux distro on MacBook from boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb, partitioning

I recently got an old MacBook (i think it is 1st gen, the HDD has 80GB of space), where everything was screwed up, so I formatted the entire Macintosh HD partition and tried to install a new OS from scratch.

I have a tails USB drive where I installed cloning the info of another Tails instance(using "clone to usb" tool). Now the USB drive contains a FAT32 partition (appart from others) with 512 bytes of block size that conitains tails OS. In Gparted, the file system options appears as these:

```
boot
esp
hidden
legacy_boot
```

There is no problem booting from that usb, I press the Option key(alt) on the mac, the boot options appear and I boot from USB (inside the boot options it appears only one drive that has "EFI" as its name, the Macintosh HD doesn't appear because there is no bootable data there).

---

The problem is when I burn another iso to another USB drive (i tried the `dd` command and rufus software, each of them with different block sizes, and each of them with different linux distros (ubuntu and fedora, both i386 versions)) the macbook doesn't recognize the pen drive, and it appears a white background every time with no cursor.

The pen drive is not the problem, as I can boot fedora from that usb drive in another computer.

When I boot with only the first USB (the one with tails) plugged, the boot options appears correctly, when I plug in both pen drives, the background stays white and the cursor doesn't appear (in boot options it seems that the cursor is visible, at least with the tails one).

When I burn from `dd` the partitions doesn't appear correctly (i think), gparted shows that the partitions are of unknown file system(ubuntu), or dont have a partition at all(fedora). Right now that new USB drive contains fedora, that I can boot in a 64bit computer, but in gparted appears as having a recursive partition, and the drive appears as empty, but as I said, I can boot fedora from another 64bit computer.

I also tried to burn the iso to a DVD and booting from that dvd, but the macbook ejects it every time before entering the boot options.

---

dd options:

```
dd if=/path/to/iso.iso of=/dev/sdd bs=512
```

and

```
dd if=/path/to/iso.iso of=/dev/sdd bs=4M
```

Rufus options:

```
FAT32, bios or uefi, 4096 cluster size, fast format and no tags nor icons.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The current Ubuntu Linux 20.04 ISO is 2.9 gigabytes if IIRC. Burning that via the CD/DVD on the MacBook will ALWAYS fail to boot on same MacBook CD/DVD. However, that same disk you just burned WILL boot on any Windows computer with a DVD drive, so it's not a total loss of the media.

Get a 4g or larger USB stick or thumb drive. Plug it into your MacBook.

Then do: disktutil list

Identify which disk is your USB drive, probably /dev/disk3, but make sure you check.   If your in OSX, right click the drive and **erase** it and go ahead and choose MS-DOS FAT file system. Then open a terminal window and unmount that drive:

umount /dev/disk3

Then:

dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/disk3 bs=1m

After about 10-15 minutes the process will complete and you will get a message that lets you know records in records out. You can disregard unless it's an error.

Then shut off your MacBook Pro, turn it back on, hold down 'Option' key, and choose the first EFI Boot drive. It will be orange and there will be two.

Your MacBook will now boot straight into the Ubuntu installer and from there it will look like any other Linux install. I chose to make my MacBook Ubuntu ONLY so at the point in the installer where it asks what to do with disk, I chose ERASE EVERYTHING and gave the whole disk to Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Get `bootia32.efi` file into the drive and edit `grub.cfg`.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide more information.  [Your suggestion, in reality, isn't entirely straight forward.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support).  You should provide specifics on how to acomplish this suggestion.